# UK Visit Visa validity

Tags: visas

I got five years UK visit visa issued in 15/10/2018 as my plan was to travel in December 2018. Now i postponed my travel to April or maybe will travel in June 2019. I would like to ask is it possible for me to use the visa or i will neet to get a new one. i.e because i did not use the visa for more than 3 months from the issue date does this mean the visa expires? Also is there any specifc period on which i have to use the visa to avoid invalidity?

Comment: You can use it ANYTIME within the five year period. Do not worry at all. Getting a five year visa means they trust you.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen that seems like an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are not required to use the UK visa at all.

You may use the visa at any time during the dates of its validity.

Answer (score -1):

Usually five Years Visa is issued after a going through a strict pipe line i.e checking your income, country ties, travel history and a valid reason for multiple visits.
You have the choice when ever you want to departure. Furthermore staying more then 180 days is not fruitful as it will show your wrong intentions.
Otherwise its no restriction how many times and when ever you travel but you must have shown a valid income that you can travel so frequently on your own expenses or sponsor.